# Android - Setting interfaces in onStart() and clearing them in onStop()

Tags: java, android, interface, android-lifecycle

I see a lot of examples of Android code setting interfaces inside the onStart(); method and clearing them with null inside onStop();

For example:

```
@Overrride
public void onStart(){
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop(){
    button.setOnClickListener(null);
}
```

Why is this? Is this good coding practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Object becomes eligible for garbage collection only when no active(non-daemon) Threads has reference to the Object.While the lifecycle of `android.app.Activity` would theoretically complete after invoking the `onDestroy()` method ,it still  needs to be dereferenced from any object which may be holding a reference to it.Therefore,the above code tries to remove its own reference from `Button` object so that it may become eligible for garbage collection.